# Como importar um pacote que possui pontuação no nome no VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Preciso importar um pacote no VueJS, cujo nome é 'vue-charts.js', e o Vue está acusando erro que não pode achar o arquivo especificado. Já tentei renomear o diretório do pacote mas não consegui. Se alguém souber como fazer isso e puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
import {BarChart} from 'vue-chart.js'
```

Erro:

```
Cannot resolve file 'vue-chart.js' less
Reports unresolved file references in JavaScript files, including CommonJS and 
AMD modules references
```

Comment: é uma dependência? instalou com npm install?

Comment: Já tentou usando full path ou tirando o .js?

Comment: instalei usando o npm install, e já tentei várias coisas, porém consegui achar uma lib parecida som o ponto no nome, obrigado pessoal

Comment: Esse `vue-chart.js` está na mesma diretoria do ficheiro que o importa?

Comment: O `vue-chart.js` está na pasta node_modules, enquanto eu importo ele na pasta src/components do Vue, em um dos componentes que irei usá-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá
Esse import que está tentando é um modulo seu? ou é de algum pacote instalado no node_modules, se for informe a url do pacote, até mesmo para testar.
se for modulo seu tente

```js
import {BarChart} from './vue-chart'
```

Comment: É um pacote do node_modules, e este é o link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chart.js. Agradeço se puder dar uma olhada...

Comment: Opa, blz cara achei o problema, esta certo assim import {BarChart} from 'vue-chart.js' , porem esse plugin é da vue 1 e talvez você está usando a vue 2

Comment: Que bom! Qual que é o problema??

Comment: achei bem bacana o plugin que estou pensando em escrever ele pra vue 2, vou pegar essa semana um tempo pra fazer isso, ai compartilho com você

Comment: Ok, fico no aguardo, muito obrigado @Heber Almeida

Comment: opa, fiz uma pesquisa achei pacotes parecidos, vê se ajuda, https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs e esse https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts ambos são com a Vue 2

Comment: Já ajuda sim, só preciso agora fazer funcionar no Quasar. Muito obrigado mais uma vez Heber